# a formula to know which datas in a sheet are contained in the other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 excel sheets. sheet1 and sheet2.

I want to know how many of my sheet1 datas are available in sheet2.

I need a formula to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the match() function?

Comment: You are providing insufficient data and reporting no attempt of your own. None can really answer your question this way. We can only guess. Try the [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) function.

Comment: Do you want to know how many, or do you want to know which ones are and aren't? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT(IF((Sheet1!$A$1:$B$10=Sheet2!$A$1:$B$10)*(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$10<>""),1,0))`
This checks for each cell in the given range (adjust this to your range) to equal I  the  same range of the 2nd sheet.
I also left out the blank cells that would equal eachother, so only actual values that equal are counted.

Comment: it didn't work. I guess that's because my datas are not in a specific order in each sheet. any other suggestion would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Can a value occur twice? How should this be handled?